# Automated 20.04 Server Installation using PXE and live server image

Tags: server, 20.04, pxe, netinstall, subiquity

How to do an fully automated Ubuntu 20.04 Server install using PXE and the *live server* image?

#### Reason

With the 20.04 release, it seems clear Ubuntu is further pushing the *live server* installer (*subiquity*) option.  The debian-installer (d-i) image has been renamed legacy.  So has the netboot installer I typically prefer.  The 20.04 release also introduces a new automated installation option for the *live server* installer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## Fully Automated Ubuntu 20.04 server install using PXE

These are steps to do a fully automated Ubuntu 20.04 Server install using PXE with the *live server* image.  I found the process to be lightly documented and filled with issues.  In these steps I am installing 20.04 on a *UEFI* based server.

**edit**: these steps were adapted for a *BIOS* based server at [Deploy Ubuntu 20.04 on bare metal or virtualbox VM by pxelinux, cloud-init doesn't pick up user-data file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238070/deploy-ubuntu-20-04-on-bare-metal-or-virtualbox-vm-by-pxelinux-cloud-init-doesn/1240068#1240068)

**edit**: these steps were created specifically for the `20.04` release of Ubuntu (`subiquity 20.04.3`).  The version of `subiquity` changes with each release.  E.g. the `20.04.3` release of Ubuntu has `subiquity 21.08.2`.  Because of the active development of `subiquity` some of the information in this post is not completely accurate for newer releases.

There are many variations to these steps possible.  They can be customized and tailored to suit one's needs.  The goal is to provide one example of how to accomplish this and to help other users overcome the issues encountered.

#### links about the installer

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Installer
- https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall
- https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/server-installer-plans-for-20-04-lts/13631
- https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/netbooting-the-live-server-installer/14510

#### config references

- https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference
- https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/config.html

#### source code

- https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/subiquity
- https://github.com/canonical/curtin

### Build a tftp server

All the following steps are run as root.  These were tested on an Ubuntu 18.04 server.

Install the tftp server and a web server

```
apt-get -y install tftpd-hpa apache2
```

Configure apache to serve files from the tftp directory

```
cat > /etc/apache2/conf-available/tftp.conf <<EOF
<Directory /var/lib/tftpboot>
        Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
        Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias /tftp /var/lib/tftpboot
EOF
a2enconf tftp
systemctl restart apache2
```

Download the live server iso

```
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso -O /var/lib/tftpboot/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso
```

Extract the kernel and initramfs from the live server iso

```
mount /var/lib/tftpboot/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso /mnt/
cp /mnt/casper/vmlinuz /var/lib/tftpboot/
cp /mnt/casper/initrd /var/lib/tftpboot/
umount  /mnt
```

Download the grub image to load via PXE

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/uefi/grub2-amd64/current/grubnetx64.efi.signed -O /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.0
```

Configure grub.  This configuration will provide a fully automated boot option as well as a manual boot option

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/tftpboot/grub
cat > /var/lib/tftpboot/grub/grub.cfg <<'EOF'
default=autoinstall
timeout=30
timeout_style=menu
menuentry "Focal Live Installer - automated" --id=autoinstall {
    echo "Loading Kernel..."
    # make sure to escape the ';' or surround argument in quotes
    linux /vmlinuz ip=dhcp url=http://${pxe_default_server}/tftp/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds="nocloud-net;s=http://${pxe_default_server}/tftp/" root=/dev/ram0 cloud-config-url=/dev/null
    echo "Loading Ram Disk..."
    initrd /initrd
}
menuentry "Focal Live Installer" --id=install {
    echo "Loading Kernel..."
    linux /vmlinuz ip=dhcp url=http://${pxe_default_server}/tftp/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso root=/dev/ram0 cloud-config-url=/dev/null
    echo "Loading Ram Disk..."
    initrd /initrd
}
EOF
```

Configure *cloud-init* with the autoinstall configuration.  I first ran the install manually to get the generated `/var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data` file to use as the basis.  I then made modifications based on my needs and errors encountered.

```
cat > /var/lib/tftpboot/meta-data <<EOF
instance-id: focal-autoinstall
EOF
```

```
cat > /var/lib/tftpboot/user-data <<'EOF'
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  # use interactive-sections to avoid an automatic reboot
  #interactive-sections:
  #  - locale
  apt:
    # even set to no/false, geoip lookup still happens
    #geoip: no
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
    - arches: [amd64, i386]
      uri: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
    - arches: [default]
      uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
  # r00tme
  identity: {hostname: focal-autoinstall, password: $6$.c38i4RIqZeF4RtR$hRu2RFep/.6DziHLnRqGOEImb15JT2i.K/F9ojBkK/79zqY30Ll2/xx6QClQfdelLe.ZjpeVYfE8xBBcyLspa/,
    username: ubuntu}
  keyboard: {layout: us, variant: ''}
  locale: en_US.UTF-8
  # interface name will probably be different
  network:
    network:
      version: 2
      ethernets:
        ens192:
          critical: true
          dhcp-identifier: mac
          dhcp4: true
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: []
    install-server: true
  # this creates an efi partition, /boot partition, and root(/) lvm volume
  storage:
    grub:
      reorder_uefi: False
    swap:
      size: 0
    config:
    - {ptable: gpt, path: /dev/sda, preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: false,
      type: disk, id: disk-sda}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 536870912, wipe: superblock, flag: boot, number: 1,
      preserve: false, grub_device: true, type: partition, id: partition-sda1}
    - {fstype: fat32, volume: partition-sda1, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-2}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 1073741824, wipe: superblock, flag: linux, number: 2,
      preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-sda2}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: partition-sda2, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-0}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: -1, flag: linux, number: 3, preserve: false,
      grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-sda3}
    - name: vg-0
      devices: [partition-sda3]
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm-volgroup-vg-0
    - {name: lv-root, volgroup: lvm-volgroup-vg-0, size: 100%, preserve: false,
      type: lvm_partition, id: lvm-partition-lv-root}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm-partition-lv-root, preserve: false, type: format,
      id: format-1}
    - {device: format-1, path: /, type: mount, id: mount-2}
    - {device: format-0, path: /boot, type: mount, id: mount-1}
    - {device: format-2, path: /boot/efi, type: mount, id: mount-3}
write_files:
  # override the kernel package
  - path: /run/kernel-meta-package
    content: |
      linux-virtual
    owner: root:root
    permissions: "0644"
  # attempt to also use an answers file by providing a file at the default path.  It did not seem to have any effect
  #- path: /subiquity_config/answers.yaml
  #  content: |
  #    InstallProgress:
  #      reboot: no
  #  owner: root:root
  #  permissions: "0644"
EOF
```

### Configure DHCP

Set the DHCP Options 66,67 according to the documentation for your DHCP server.

### Boot your server

At this point, you should be able to boot your UEFI based server and perform a completely automatic install.

## Errors encountered

- The server being installed requires over 2 GB of RAM.  I ended up creating a VM with 3 GB for testing.  **EDIT** Using the `cloud-config-url=/dev/null` kernel argument will prevent `cloud-init` from unnecessarily downloading the iso, which [reduces the memory required](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-20-04-autoinstall-with-2g-ram/21711/2), reduces network traffic, and speeds up boot time.
- The generated `/var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data` file was broken in the following ways

  - There is no `version` property, which caused a validation failure.  I added the property
  - The `network` section required another level of nesting.  This bug is mentioned in the config reference
  - The `preserve` property on each item in `storage` `config` needed to be set to **false**.  Otherwise *curtin* would not install on a blank disk
  - The `keyboard` property `toggle` was set to null, which caused a validation failure.  I simply removed the property
- When *curtin* installs on a UEFI device, it reorders the boot order so the current boot option is first in the list.  The result is that network boot becomes the first option the next reboot.  So when the install is done and the reboot happens... you end up in the PXE environment again instead of booting from disk.  I found an **undocumented** *curtin* option `reorder_uefi`.  Luckily, *subiquity* happens to pass this configuration to *curtin*
- The `apt` config option `geoip` doesn't seem to work.  There were always logs for geoip requests
- Using human readable values for partition sizes (e.g. `size: 512M`) resulted in the size being stored as a float, leading to errors when sizing LVM volumes as a percentage.  Avoiding human readable values seems to fix this

## Other missing features

I didn't dig into these as much.  They are based on what my preseed files would do.  Most of them could probably be fixed with clever use of `early-commands`, `late-commands`, and *cloud-init*.  I may have also missed something

- A way to set the timezone
- A way to set the root password
- A way to configure an apt only proxy.  I like to use `apt-cacher-ng` for apt, but it does not work as a general proxy.  The installer assumes any proxy you configure is for everything
- A way to pause at the end of the install instead of automatically rebooting.  The workaround is to add a value to `interactive-sections`, but that results in 3 pauses
- Allow direct *curtin* configuration.  You have to create yaml for *cloud-init* to provide yaml to *subiquity*, which then generates yaml for *curtin*.  It would provide more configuration flexibility to be able to provide the curtin yaml directly
- Allow direct *cloud-init* configuration.  You have to create yaml for *cloud-init* to provide yaml to *subiquity*, which then generates yaml for *cloud-init* on the installed machine.  These files should be easy to modify with `late-commands`, but I did not try it
- Ability to choose the kernel package.  I found that the kernel image installed is based on what is written to `/run/kernel-meta-package`.  This is hardcoded to `linux-generic` in the initramfs.  I prefer to use the `linux-virtual` package for VMs.  I was able to use the *cloud-init* configuration to overwrite the file

## Edit 1

The resulting `/target/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data` file used by cloud-init during first boot.  The replies indicate the `lock-passwd` property has a typo and may affect some users

```
#cloud-config
growpart: {mode: 'off'}
locale: en_US.UTF-8
preserve_hostname: true
resize_rootfs: false
ssh_pwauth: true
users:
- gecos: ubuntu
  groups: [adm, cdrom, dip, plugdev, lxd, sudo]
  lock-passwd: false
  name: ubuntu
  passwd: $6$.c38i4RIqZeF4RtR$hRu2RFep/.6DziHLnRqGOEImb15JT2i.K/F9ojBkK/79zqY30Ll2/xx6QClQfdelLe.ZjpeVYfE8xBBcyLspa/
  shell: /bin/bash
```

Comment: This is an amazing compilation of what you need to get this buggy installer going. I wish I had stumbled upon this before I had to research all these gotchas, too.

Comment: I don't get it. The identity settings don't get used no matter what I tried. I end up with a system I cannot login to.

Comment: The identity part can be tough to troubleshoot because the user doesn't get created until the first boot.  You can have the installer pause before a reboot.  Then access the terminal with `Alt-F2`.  Check the files in `/target/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net`.  This is what _cloud-init_ will use during the first boot. You can at least verify the username and hash are being set properly.
You could also create a user manually in the `/target` install so you can login after boot and check what _cloud-init_ does during the first boot.  Try a `chroot /target` then `adduser`

Comment: Yes. Checking the cloud-init config reveals there is an error. `lock-passwd` instead of `lock_passwd`. I wonder why it works for you.  
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subiquity/+bug/1879485/

Comment: Interesting. I ran through the process again and my `/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud-net/user-data` has `lock-passwd: false`.  Upon first boot the user is created without any error.  I'll add the file contents to the answer since I can't format it here

Comment: This looks like the only option for specifying the parameters of the autoinstall is to place a user-data file in the root directory of the tftp server in the autoinstall format. Is that correct? Is there a way to specify a file that changes based on which machine you're installing to?

Comment: @RobertRapplean if you want more dynamic configuration then you can get creative with `early-commands`.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309505/choose-autoinstall-config-by-bios-serial-or-mac and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290624/fetch-autoinstall-based-on-mac

Comment: Thank you so so much for sharing the information about `cloud-config-url=/dev/null`. Encountered that problem but didn't know how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for this....  You say you were able to install in 3GB - with Cloud-Init/21.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 that's now 5GB...  How can I mount of up the ISO without coping the whole thing into RAM?  NFS would work, but how?

Comment: If I install the ZFS packages and then install - will the auto generated autoinstall file contain the commands to install ZFS libraries before creating the partitions?

Answer (score 1):

I set the timezone in the user-data file's 'user-data' section, and also set the root password there; like this:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  ...
  user-data:
    timezone: Europe/London
    disable_root: false
    chpasswd:
      list: |
        root:HASHEDPASSWORD
  ...
```

Comment: Can you clarify how the hashed password is created? I haven't seen any mention of how to hash or what utility to use to hash a password.