# Deploy Ubuntu 20.04 on bare metal or virtualbox VM by pxelinux, cloud-init doesn't pick up user-data file

Tags: 20.04, pxe, cloud-init

I've been deploying Ubuntu (since 12.04) along with other Linux with pxelinux many years. With the Debian-installer, it works just fine. These days I've been trying to deploy 20.04, which also works basically. Only one question, the "user-data" file never been picked up. No matter what I do, I always get all the questions asked from the installer. Here is my environment:

1. I created a user-data file under /var/www/html/ubuntu/cloud-init of the file server, and its content is as this:

```
## cloud-config

autoinstall:
  version: 1
  apt:
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
    - arches: [default]
      uri: [...]/images/ubuntu

  identity: {realname: wrsadmin, username: wrsadmin}
  keyboard: {layout: us, toggle: null, variant: ''}
  locale: en_US
  network:
    ethernets:
      enp0s3:
        critical: true
        dhcp-identifier: mac
        dhcp4: true
        nameservers:
          addresses: [128.224.160.11, 128.224.160.12]
          search: [wrs.com., corp.ad.wrs.com.]
    version: 2
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: []
    install-server: true

  late-commands:
    - rm -f /target/etc/resolv.conf
    - wget -O /target/etc/resolv.conf [...]/ubuntu/resolv.conf
    - chattr +i /target/etc/resolv.conf
```

2. "default" file of pxelinux. As you can see below, when I use the Debian-Installer netboot files, PXE works, and preseed works too. When I use cloud-init format netboot files, PXE works too, the 900MB server live image is loaded successfully. But, the "autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=[...]/ubuntu/cloud-init/" is like it doesn't exist.

## Debian-installer + preseed:

```
LABEL Ubuntu 20.04 x64 legacy
  MENU LABEL Ubuntu 20.04 x64 legacy
  TEXT HELP
  Ubuntu 20.04 x64 legacy
  ENDTEXT
  KERNEL Linux/Ubuntu2004/linux
  APPEND vga=normal initrd=Linux/Ubuntu2004/initrd.gz locale=en_US.UTF-8 keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us ipv6.disable=1 url=[...]/ubuntu/preseed/preseed2004.cfg
```

## Cloud-init + user-data

```
LABEL Ubuntu 20.04 x64
  MENU LABEL Ubuntu 20.04 x64
  TEXT HELP
  Ubuntu 20.04 x64
  ENDTEXT
  KERNEL Linux/Ubuntu2004/vmlinuz
  APPEND initrd=Linux/Ubuntu2004/initrd ip=dhcp url=[...]/images/ubuntuExtra/ubuntu2004/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=[...]/ubuntu/cloud-init/
```

Would you please help to diagnose which part I did wrong?

Comment: Make sure you use an url that can be looked up properly and not use a short-name (i.e. non FQN). Try use the IP-address as source if that changes anything.
Also if you use https with selfsigned certs will be problematic. Not sure how to solve that with autoinstall.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to use these steps to do an autoinstall on a BIOS based VM.  They are slightly modified from [my UEFI steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235724/376778).  Hopefully they will provide an example to help you figure out your problem.  You can tailor them to your environment

### Build a tftp server

All the following steps are run as root.  These were tested on an Ubuntu 18.04 server.

Install the tftp server, web server, and syslinux files

```
apt-get -y install tftpd-hpa apache2 pxelinux
```

Configure apache to serve files from the tftp directory

```
cat > /etc/apache2/conf-available/tftp.conf <<EOF
<Directory /var/lib/tftpboot>
        Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes
        Require all granted
</Directory>
Alias /tftp /var/lib/tftpboot
EOF
a2enconf tftp
systemctl restart apache2
```

Copy the syslinux files to the tftp directory

```
cp /usr/lib/PXELINUX/gpxelinux.0 /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.0.bios
cp /usr/lib/syslinux/modules/bios/*.c32 /var/lib/tftpboot
```

Download the live server iso

```
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso -O /var/lib/tftpboot/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso
```

Extract the kernel and initramfs from the live server iso

```
mount /var/lib/tftpboot/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso /mnt/
cp /mnt/casper/vmlinuz /var/lib/tftpboot/
cp /mnt/casper/initrd /var/lib/tftpboot/
umount  /mnt
```

Configure syslinux

```
MYIP=$(hostname --ip-address)
mkdir -p /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg
cat > /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default <<EOF
DEFAULT vesamenu.c32
TIMEOUT 600
ONTIMEOUT focal-live-install-autoinstall
PROMPT 0

NOESCAPE 1

LABEL focal-live-install
        MENU DEFAULT
        MENU label Install focal
        KERNEL vmlinuz
        INITRD initrd
        APPEND root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp url=http://${MYIP}/tftp/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso

LABEL focal-live-install-autoinstall
        MENU DEFAULT
        MENU label Install focal - autoinstall
        KERNEL vmlinuz
        INITRD initrd
        APPEND root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp url=http://${MYIP}/tftp/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://${MYIP}/tftp/cloud-init-bios/ cloud-config-url=/dev/null

EOF
```

Configure *cloud-init* with the autoinstall configuration.  I first ran the install manually to get the generated `/var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data` file to use as the basis.  I then made modifications based on my needs and errors encountered.

```
mkdir -p /var/lib/tftpboot/cloud-init-bios/
cat > /var/lib/tftpboot/cloud-init-bios/meta-data <<EOF
instance-id: focal-autoinstall
EOF
```

```
cat > /var/lib/tftpboot/cloud-init-bios/user-data <<'EOF'
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  # use interactive-sections to avoid an automatic reboot
  #interactive-sections:
  #  - locale
  apt:
    # even set to no/false, geoip lookup still happens
    #geoip: no
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
    - arches: [amd64, i386]
      uri: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
    - arches: [default]
      uri: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports
  # r00tme
  identity: {hostname: focal-autoinstall, password: $6$.c38i4RIqZeF4RtR$hRu2RFep/.6DziHLnRqGOEImb15JT2i.K/F9ojBkK/79zqY30Ll2/xx6QClQfdelLe.ZjpeVYfE8xBBcyLspa/,
    username: ubuntu}
  keyboard: {layout: us, variant: ''}
  locale: en_US.UTF-8
  # interface name will probably be different
  network:
    network:
      version: 2
      ethernets:
        ens192:
          critical: true
          dhcp-identifier: mac
          dhcp4: true
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    authorized-keys: []
    install-server: true
  # this creates an bios_grub partition, /boot partition, and root(/) lvm volume
  storage:
    config:
    - {ptable: gpt, path: /dev/sda, wipe: superblock, preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: true,
      type: disk, id: disk-sda}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 1048576, flag: bios_grub, number: 1, preserve: false,
      type: partition, id: partition-0}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 1073741824, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 2,
      preserve: false, type: partition, id: partition-1}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: partition-1, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-0}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: -1, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 3,
      preserve: false, type: partition, id: partition-2}
    - name: ubuntu-vg
      devices: [partition-2]
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm_volgroup-0
    - {name: ubuntu-lv, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 100%, preserve: false,
      type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-0}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-0, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-1}
    - {device: format-1, path: /, type: mount, id: mount-1}
    - {device: format-0, path: /boot, type: mount, id: mount-0}
write_files:
  # override the kernel package
  - path: /run/kernel-meta-package
    content: |
      linux-virtual
    owner: root:root
    permissions: "0644"
  # attempt to also use an answers file by providing a file at the default path.  It did not seem to have any effect
  #- path: /subiquity_config/answers.yaml
  #  content: |
  #    InstallProgress:
  #      reboot: no
  #  owner: root:root
  #  permissions: "0644"
EOF
```

### Configure DHCP

Set the DHCP Options 66,67 according to the documentation for your DHCP server.

### Boot your server

At this point, you should be able to boot your UEFI based server and perform a completely automatic install.

Comment: Hello Sir, I understand each part of your configuration. Thank you for your kindly help. But I failed to figure out why the live image doesn't load the autoinstall file I specified. I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 3):

When I did this with a UEFI based server (which uses grub instead of syslinux) I had to escape the semicolon in the command line.

Try changing

```
ds=nocloud-net;s=http://blah/ubuntu/cloud-init/
```

to

```
ds=nocloud-net\;s=http://blah/ubuntu/cloud-init/
```

I found the easiest way to check in the installer environment is to use `alt-f2` to get a console and use the command

```
dmesg | grep 'Command line'
```

That will show if the full `ds` argument is being passed or if it only passes up to the `;`

Comment: Thank you sir for you reply. "escape the semicolon" I've tried, which doesn't work. I tried both today and use "Alt+F2" to see the full arguments that had been passed, no matter escape or not, all arguments were passed.

Comment: You're right, escaping the semicolon is **not** needed in the pxelinux.cfg.  You can check your web server logs to see if the cloud-init files are being downloaded.  The installer logs in `/var/log` might also contain any errors if they are being downloaded but the syntax is bad

Comment: Hello Sir, I check out the httpd logs on my http server. Here is what I got when the installer is running: comment is too short. Please see the answer from me below

Comment: I posted another answer with complete steps that I used successfully.  I hope it helps you figure out what you're missing

Answer (score 0):

There are only three entries generated in /var/log/httpd/access_log (and there is no new entries in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`):

```
128.224.180.84 - - [14/May/2020:09:48:45 +0800] "GET /images/ubuntuExtra/ubuntu2004/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 952107008 "-" "Wget"
128.224.180.84 - - [14/May/2020:09:49:35 +0800] "GET /images/ubuntuExtra/ubuntu2004/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 952107008 "-" "Cloud-Init/20.1-10-g71af48df-0ubuntu5"
128.224.180.84 - - [14/May/2020:09:50:06 +0800] "GET /images/ubuntuExtra/ubuntu2004/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 952107008 "-" "Cloud-Init/20.1-10-g71af48df-0ubuntu5"
```

The first entry shows the installer is loading the live image, which I can understand.

But I don't understand the following two entries. And there is certainly no entry for loading the autoinstall file, which I have no idea why.