# Only half the capacity of the SSD available on PXE autoinstall

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, pxe

I used a PXE install on a computer with the following relevant parameters in user-data:

```
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm
      match:
        ssd: yes
```

meaning the SSD (machine only contains one) should be formatted and partitioned automatically.

After the installation finishes the partition information is as I expected

```
sudo partx -s /dev/sda
NR   START       END   SECTORS   SIZE NAME UUID
 1    2048      4095      2048     1M      c22ce821-a730-4ba4-9992-3014acb4c332
 2    4096   2101247   2097152     1G      24379366-30d3-4967-b9d7-31a42ea2043d
 3 2101248 250066943 247965696 118.2G      d15a6cd2-b73e-427b-b7ea-0d99f6c6fce5
```

Yet free space is only about half what it should be. Also their are weird extra mounts

```
 sudo lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8790
loop1                       7:1    0  55.3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop2                       7:2    0  71.5M  1 loop /snap/lxd/16740
sda                         8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0 118.2G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  59.1G  0 lvm  /
```

How can I set the auto installer parameters that I have the whole 118.2G available?

Thanks in advance.

[Workaround]

If you replace `name: lvm`with `name: direct`I get the full capacity but then obviousl LVM is not working. The Machine also then does not seem to have a separate boot partition:

```
sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  29.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8790
loop1    7:1    0  55.3M  1 loop /snap/core18/1885
loop2    7:2    0  71.5M  1 loop /snap/lxd/16740
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part
└─sda2   8:2    0 119.2G  0 part /
```

I would prefer to have the full capacity available with LVM.

[/Workaround]

[Config with LVM]

pxelinux.cfg:

```
DEFAULT install
LABEL install
  KERNEL vmlinuz
  INITRD initrd
  APPEND root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp url=http://10.2.1.20/efi_focal/ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 ip=dhcp ipv6.disa>
```

user-data:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  early-commands:
    - systemctl stop ssh # otherwise packer tries to connect and exceed max attempts
  network:
    network:
      version: 2
      ethernets:
        eth0:
          dhcp4: yes
          dhcp-identifier: mac
          optional: true
        eth1:
          dhcp4: yes
          dhcp-identifier: mac
          optional: true
        eth2:
          dhcp4: yes
          dhcp-identifier: mac
          optional: true
        eth3:
          dhcp4: yes
          dhcp-identifier: mac
          optional: true
        eth4:
          dhcp4: yes
          dhcp-identifier: mac
          optional: true
        eth5:
          dhcp4: yes
          dhcp-identifier: mac
          optional: true
  locale: en_US
  keyboard:
    layout: de
  apt:
    http_proxy: http://10.2.1.1:8080/
    https_proxy: http://10.2.1.1:8080/
    preserve_sources_list: false
    primary:
      - arches: [amd64]
        uri: "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/"
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm
      match:
        ssd: yes
  ssh:
    install-server: yes
    allow-pw: yes
  identity:
    hostname: decosrv02
    password: Hash of the PW
    username: ipc 
  packages:
    - net-tools
    - docker
    - docker-compose
  user-data:
    idisable_root: false
  late-commands:
    - echo 'ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' > /target/etc/sudoers.d/ubuntu
    - sed -ie 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=.*/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 ipv6.disable=1 biosdevname=0"/' /target/etc/default/grub
    - curtin in-target --target /target update-grub2
    - apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

[/Config with LVM]

[resize by hand]

```
ipc@decosrv02:~$ sudo lvextend -l 100%FREE ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  Please specify a logical volume path.

ipc@decosrv02:~$ sudo lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  New size given (15134 extents) not larger than existing size (15135 extents)

ipc@decosrv02:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 15498240 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

[/resize by hand]

Comment: I have found a workaround and edited the question accordingly.

Comment: You don't have to use the `layout` setting.  You can configure the storage section explicitly.  This would allow you to configure partitions, volume groups, and logical volumes.  With logical volumes you can specify 100% as a size

Comment: @AndrewLowther I discovered that via the IRC chat I had with the cloud-init folks, and have an example config I'm working on converting to an answer.  Is a headache though because you have to sort of do a from-scratch disk config from disk partition table to the filesystems - and *that* isn't immediately clear to many (nor myself even after pouring through Curtin docs)

Comment: I'll post the config I've used as an answer.  It might be a useful example.

Answer (score 2):

This is a storage configuration I've used.  It will create a layout of

- 1MB bios_grub
- 1GB /boot partition
- 100% of remaining space is used by LVM for a root logical volume

Based on your output in the original question I believe you are installing on a BIOS based machine.  I took this config section from my full BIOS autoinstall example at https://askubuntu.com/a/1240068/376778

I haven't actually tested configuring `storage` using the `match` option.  The **Disk selection extensions** section suggests this should work: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference

```
  storage:
    config:
    - {ptable: gpt, match: {ssd: yes}, wipe: superblock, preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: true,
      type: disk, id: disk-sda}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 1048576, flag: bios_grub, number: 1, preserve: false,
      type: partition, id: partition-0}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: 1073741824, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 2,
      preserve: false, type: partition, id: partition-1}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: partition-1, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-0}
    - {device: disk-sda, size: -1, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 3,
      preserve: false, type: partition, id: partition-2}
    - name: ubuntu-vg
      devices: [partition-2]
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm_volgroup-0
    - {name: ubuntu-lv, volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0, size: 100%, preserve: false,
      type: lvm_partition, id: lvm_partition-0}
    - {fstype: ext4, volume: lvm_partition-0, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-1}
    - {device: format-1, path: /, type: mount, id: mount-1}
    - {device: format-0, path: /boot, type: mount, id: mount-0}
```