# What would be the best way to go about installing the same packages every day

Tags: 20.04, bash, scripts

At my job i need to install *buntu along with some packages, and do some system configurations everyday. I actually don't mind doing it but can't help this feeling of "If you do it every day you should probably came up with a solution to make it faster" so i thought about writing a simple bash script that installs everything I need, which would be helpful, but wont take care of the config part (I could write a script for that too, but i'm still not sure how to do it) so i thought about making my own distro with everything i need so i just install it and i wouldn't have to do anything else.
What do you guys think is the right way to go about this? making my own distro or making a script that installs the stuff i need?
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to install an entire operating system and programs every day? It seems like there would be a better solution just to this alone.

Comment: @Esther Because I provide new employees with a ready to go laptop!  how would you go about that? thank you for answering!

Comment: Sounds like a job for clonezilla.https://clonezilla.org/

Comment: @bruni thanks! this is very helpful! i'll look into it.

Comment: Or a job for PXE boot + Cloud-init. One example at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238070