# ubuntu 22.04 pxe auto install hangs like forever

Tags: 22.04, pxe

I already make a bootable auto install ISO of ubuntu 22.04 server , and now I want to provide it in my original PXE environment

my PXE IP: 192.168.11.7

hereis my dhcpd.conf about pxelinux

```
 filename "bios/pxelinux.0";
    next-server 192.168.11.7;
```

and then add this section in my pxe boot menu

```
label Ubuntu 22.04 Server auto install
menu label Ubuntu 22.04 Server auto install
kernel tftp://192.168.11.7/images/ubuntu/22.04/amd64/vmlinuz
initrd tftp://192.168.11.7/images/ubuntu/22.04/amd64/initrd.gz
append ip=dhcp cloud-config-url=/dev/null url=http://192.168.11.7/jammy-server/ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.11.7/jammy-server/ # Don't forget the slash at the end.
```

then upload ISO file , vmlinuz/initrd.gz (extracted from the ISO ) , user-data/meta-data ( which I make ) to http://192.168.11.7/jammy-sever/

[image]

all these files can be downloaded.

then I restart dhcp service , tftpd service , nginx service , create a VM in proxmox to see if PXE works , here is the screen recording.

https://sendvid.com/yoylzub3

the installer just hangs here like forever , althrouuogh I can start new tty with alt+f2/f3/f4... but it's all black screen , so I can't see the installer log ( if there is any ) to see what's going on.

I'm stuck here for couple days , I really need some advice to move on.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: How much RAM does the VM in proxmox have?  I found 3GB of RAM is needed when using the 22.04 live-server installer over PXE.  With too little RAM the machine simply hangs.

Comment: 8GB RAM , and would you please consider to share how to configure PXE to deploy 22.04 ?

Comment: The 22.04 process should be nearly identical to the 20.04 process (https://askubuntu.com/a/1240068/376778).  You video shows errors starting at `cloud-init-local.service`.  This is before the `user-data` file would be downloaded, but if the Proxmox VM has a local config (e.g. `cicustom` value) it could be breaking something.

Comment: You can also try to PXE boot without the `autoinstall ds=...` arguments to see if the interactive installer starts properly.

Comment: without autoinstall part , kernel panic.

https://i.imgur.com/VoUYlMC.png

Comment: That kernel panic usually means the `initrd` line is missing or wrong.  Without the initramfs the kernel does not have the modules needed for the file system.  It is hard to say for certain without more information.  I saw your other post saying you got a Proxmox VM working with PXE and autoinstall, so I hope that means you figured out your problem.