# Ubuntu 22.04 autoinstall pxe not getting user-data

Tags: 22.04, pxe, autoinstall

testing on VirtualBox an automated install of ubuntu desktop, i have a router, dhcp, tftp, http server.

This is my `pxelinux.cfg/default`:

```
UI menu.c32
LABEL Ubuntu
  MENU LABEL Ubuntu
  KERNEL ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz
  INITRD ubuntu/casper/initrd
  APPEND root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp cloud-config-url=/dev/null url=http://192.168.1.1/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso autoinstall ds='nocloud-net\;s=http://192.168.1.1/' ---
```

But the automated install doesn't work. I still get to the install form...

I use a minimal autoinstall `user-data` and empty `meta-data` on my http server:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: test
    password: $6$TgOD2MaHJ5/yy6s4$J7QZMZe/lUqOboU6M3B/MqXEnovVil2n4N1OkfDgP7.RcBXUPGxehSPF6Vy8fPt9yHf61LAGkIL8zLjFVN88i.
    username: test
```

on the `/var/log/apache2/access.log` only the ubuntu ISO is requested by the pxe boot. But on live environment I can download the user-data and meta-data files with wget.

with `journalctl | grep autoinstall` I get

```
Jan 12 11:08:49 ubuntu kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp url=http://192.168.1.1/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.1.1/ cloud-config-url=/dev/null --- initrd=ubuntu/casper/initrd
Jan 12 11:08:49 ubuntu kernel: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp url=http://192.168.1.1/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.1.1/ cloud-config-url=/dev/null --- initrd=ubuntu/casper/initrd
Jan 12 11:08:49 ubuntu kernel: Unknown kernel command line parameters "autoinstall --- BOOT_IMAGE=ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp url=http://192.168.1.1/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.1.1/ cloud-config-url=/dev/null", will be passed to user space.
Jan 12 11:08:49 ubuntu kernel:     autoinstall
Jan 12 11:09:06 ubuntu /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1506]: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp url=http://192.168.1.1/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.1.1/ cloud-config-url=/dev/null --- initrd=ubuntu/casper/initrd
```

I have tested with ubuntu server 22.04, UEFI and BIOS, with quotes and backslash for ds parameter but none of them seems to work

Comment: The standard 22.04 desktop installer does not use autoinstall.  The server installer does.  PXELinux does not require quoting or escaping in the kernel parameters.  See a full example at https://askubuntu.com/a/1240068/376778

Comment: yes! I replaced the ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso with ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso and the auto install is now working, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made two errors:

- the iso must be the live-server one not the desktop as well as the initrd and the vmlinuz file served by tftp
- in my pxe config :

  - `cloud-config-url` should be `<URL TO user-data>` not `/dev/null`
  - `ds=nocloud-net s=<URL TO DIRECTORY CONTAINING user-data>` works, no quotes or escape sequence required

thanks to dummyuser and Andrew Lowther, both of your answer were necessary

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, the server does not find your `user-data` file.
You need to change the `APPEND` line slightly

```
APPEND root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp cloud-config-url=<URL TO user-data> url=http://192.168.1.1/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net s=<URL TO DIRECTORY CONTAINING user-data>
```

please replace `<URL TO user-data>` and `<URL TO DIRECTORY CONTAINING user-data>` with your values.

Comment: thank you, but it is still not working... same issue the user-data file is not requested

Comment: it works in my environment since years. did you check the log of the web-Server?