# 20.04 live server automated install hangs on "finish: subiquity/Refresh: SUCCESS: completed", not able to login

Tags: boot, 20.04, preseed, pxe, subiquity

I try to install 20.04 live server image on bare metal BIOS based device. I'm following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235723/automated-20-04-server-installation-using-pxe-and-live-server-image). I managed to set up dnsmasq, TFTP and HTTP servers, but after running user-data script booting hangs with: [finish: subiquity/Refresh: SUCCESS: completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve2dO.png). I tried ssh to that machine, but all credentials stored in user-data file are denied. After reboot it isn't even booting from hard drive, so I guess installation process fails. I'm using user-data and meta-data files from [official docs](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart).
user-data:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:                                                                          
  version: 1                                                                          
  identity:                                                                           
    hostname: ubuntu20
    # ubuntu                                                       
    password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof
0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"                                                  
    username: ubuntu
```

meta-data:

```
instance-id: ubuntu20
```

I reproduced steps from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subiquity/+bug/1879485/), so I tried adding like:

```
user-data:                                                                    
  disable_root: false 
  users:                                                                              
    name: root                                                                        
      lock_passwd: false                                                                
      password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
    name: ubuntuuser
      password: "$6$exDY1mhS4KUYCE/2$zmn9ToZwTKLhCw.b4/b.ZRTIZM30JZ4QrOQ2aOXJ8yk96xpcCof0kxKwuX1kqLG/ygbJ1f8wxED22bTL4F46P0"
      lock_passwd: false
refresh-installer:
  channel: edge
  update: yes
ssh:
  authorized-keys: "ssh-key [...] user@host"
```

But no improve at all. I tried with `lock-passwd`.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you don't need any proxy. If you do need, add proxy configuration to `user-data`:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:                                                                          
  version: 1
  proxy: http://proxy-ip:proxy-port
```