# Ubuntu 20.04 installer downloads ISO more than once

Tags: server, 20.04, cloud-init, subiquity, netinstall

I have been working through the example posted by Andrew Lowther at [Automated 20.04 Server Installation using PXE and live server image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235723/automated-20-04-server-installation-using-pxe-and-live-server-image/1235724) .  For example using a linux cmdline similar to:

```
linux /vmlinuz ip=dhcp url=http://${pxe_default_server}/tftp/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net\;s=http://${pxe_default_server}/tftp/
```

....and got things working (Thanks Andrew!)

Another question I have after working with this a bit.  As one can see, the installer is going to downlaoad the ISO from `http://${pxe_default_server}/tftp/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso`  in that example.  In my httpd logs, I can see that the ISO gets downloaded 3 times over the network when doing one automated install. Is there a way I can make it not do that?

```
192.168.1.225 - - [06/Apr/2021:22:09:47 +0000] "GET /ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 958398464 "-" "Wget"
192.168.1.225 - - [06/Apr/2021:22:13:24 +0000] "GET /ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 958398464 "-" "Cloud-Init/20.2-45-g5f7825e2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1"
192.68.1.225 - - [06/Apr/2021:22:16:50 +0000] "GET /ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 958398464 "-" "Cloud-Init/20.2-45-g5f7825e2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I saw this [got an answer on Discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-20-04-installer-downloads-iso-more-than-once/21697/4), but I thought I'd share what I found.

Adding `cloud-config-url=/dev/null` to the kernel arguments does prevent `cloud-init` from downloading the ISO, and the ISO is only downloaded once. The full grub line is now

```
linux /vmlinuz ip=dhcp url=http://${pxe_default_server}/tftp/ubuntu-20.04-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net\;s=http://${pxe_default_server}/tftp/ cloud-config-url=/dev/null
```

#### why this happens

When using PXE, the `url=` parameter must be added to the kernel arguments to specify the location of the ISO file.  I believe `casper` handles this and the argument [must be in the form](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/tree/scripts/casper#n50) `url=*.iso`

`cloud-init` will also parse the `url` kernel argument and attempt to use it (twice, apparently).  From https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/fc5d541529d9f4a076998b7b4a3c90bb4be0000d/doc/sources/kernel-cmdline.txt

> when 'cloud-init start' runs, it will check to
> see if if one of 'cloud-config-url' or 'url' appear in key/value fashion
> in the kernel command line ... Cloud-init will then read the contents of the given url.

As the Discourse post points out, the `cloud-config-url` is [checked first](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/fc5d541529d9f4a076998b7b4a3c90bb4be0000d/cloudinit/cmd/main.py#L126), so you can use a kludge to avoid the extra downloads.

Comment: I was starting down the path of reverse engineering how this all works.  Thanks so much!