# pxe autoinstall fails with ubuntu 20.04.04

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation, pxe, cloud-init

I use .pcengines.ch (apu2) hardware and set up a pxe environment autoinstall works with ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso but it fails when upgrading to ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso.

Log of www-server for ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso:

```
2022/07/26 11:52:59 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 27
192.168.41.20 - - [26/Jul/2022:11:54:16 +0000] "GET /ksfiles/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 1261371392 "-" "Wget" "-"
192.168.41.20 - - [26/Jul/2022:11:55:23 +0000] "GET /ksfiles/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 1261371392 "-" "Cloud-Init/21.2-3-g899bfaa9-0ubuntu2~20.04.1" "-"
192.168.41.20 - - [26/Jul/2022:11:56:03 +0000] "GET /ksfiles/ubuntu-20.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 1261371392 "-" "Cloud-Init/21.2-3-g899bfaa9-0ubuntu2~20.04.1" "-"
192.168.41.20 - - [26/Jul/2022:11:56:08 +0000] "GET /ksfiles/apu21/meta-data HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Cloud-Init/21.2-3-g899bfaa9-0ubuntu2~20.04.1" "-"
192.168.41.20 - - [26/Jul/2022:11:56:08 +0000] "GET /ksfiles/apu21/user-data HTTP/1.1" 200 1916 "-" "Cloud-Init/21.2-3-g899bfaa9-0ubuntu2~20.04.1" "-"
192.168.41.20 - - [26/Jul/2022:11:56:08 +0000] "GET /ksfiles/apu21/vendor-data HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "Cloud-Init/21.2-3-g899bfaa9-0ubuntu2~20.04.1" "-"
192.168.41.20 - - [26/Jul/2022:11:56:08 +0000] "GET /ksfiles/apu21/vendor-data/ HTTP/1.1" 200 198 "-" "Cloud-Init/21.2-3-g899bfaa9-0ubuntu2~20.04.1" "-"
```

Log of www-server for ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso:

```
192.168.41.20 - - [26/Jul/2022:12:24:49 +0000] "GET /ksfiles/ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 1331691520 "-" "Wget" "-"
192.168.41.20 - - [26/Jul/2022:12:25:59 +0000] "GET /ksfiles/ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 1331691520 "-" "Cloud-Init/21.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.1" "-"
192.168.41.20 - - [26/Jul/2022:12:26:36 +0000] "GET /ksfiles/ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 1331691520 "-" "Cloud-Init/21.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.1" "-"
```

I find the Error message in the boot log on Console:

```
[  OK  ] Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
[  138.071529] Out of memory: Killed process 1125 (cloud-init) total-vm:2661804kB, anon-rss:2475148kB, file-rss:2784kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:4916kB oom_score_adj:0
[FAILED] Failed to start Initial cl…ob (metadata service crawler).
See 'systemctl status cloud-init.service' for details.
```

my pxe config file looks like:
content of pxelinux.cfg/01-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX:

```
    DEFAULT install
    LABEL install
      KERNEL vmlinuz
      INITRD initrd
      APPEND root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp url=http://192.168.41.5/ksfiles/ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.41.5/ksfiles/apu21/ console=ttyS0,115200n8 earlyprint=serial,ttyS0,115200
```

To me it looks like the cloud-init process is killed during boot due to OOM. is there a significant difference between 20.04.03 and 20.04.04 ?
how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This certainly looks like an Out-Of-Memory issue.  An easy way to reduce the memory requirement is to add to your `APPEND` line the argument `cloud-config-url=/dev/null`.  This argument will prevent the iso from being downloaded by `cloud-init` two times.

With the `cloud-config-url` argument I've been able to reliably PXE autoinstall 20.04 with 2GB of RAM (I believe this includes 20.04.4), and 22.04 with 3GB of RAM.  Less RAM than that tends to be unreliable.

**See also**

- [Ubuntu 20.04 installer downloads ISO more than once](https://askubuntu.com/q/1329734/376778)
- https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-20-04-autoinstall-with-2g-ram/21711/2
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1240068/376778

Comment: Hi, looks like you pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

my hardware has 4 GB - should not be a general memory Issue ...

I changed the APPEND parameter to

```
APPEND root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=2000000 fsck.mode=skip  ip=dhcp url=http://192.168.41.5/ksfiles/ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall  ds=nocloud-net cloud-config-url=http://192.168.41.5/ksfiles/apu21/user-data s=http://192.168.41.5/ksfiles/apu21 console=ttyS0,115200n8 earlyprint=serial,ttyS0,115200
```

and the www log looks like

```
192.168.41.20 - - [27/Jul/2022:18:12:43 +0000] "GET /ksfiles/ubuntu-20.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 1331691520 "-" "Wget" "-"
192.168.41.20 - - [27/Jul/2022:18:13:18 +0000] "GET /ksfiles/apu21/user-data HTTP/1.1" 200 1916 "-" "Cloud-Init/21.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.1" "-"
192.168.41.20 - - [27/Jul/2022:18:13:24 +0000] "GET /ksfiles/apu21/user-data HTTP/1.1" 200 1916 "-" "Cloud-Init/21.4-0ubuntu1~20.04.1" "-"
```

autoinstall starts :-)