# Install with PXE of ubuntu 22.04 blocked

Tags: 22.04, pxe

I would like to install ubuntu 22.04 automatically with the PXE.
When using the "cloud-init" script the installation freezes on "connecting ..." with a looping animation "/-|/" (screen attached)

I don't know what is blocking and I can't find any error message in the logs

Can you help me and do you know what this "connecting" step does?

**pxelinux.cfg/default**

```
menu title Ubuntu installer

label jammy
        menu label Install Ubuntu Jammy (22.04)
        menu default
        kernel casper/vmlinuz
        initrd casper/initrd
        append root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp cloud-config-url=/dev/null url=http://192.168.42.151/jammy-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.42.151/jammy/ # Don't forget the slash at the end.

prompt 0
timeout 0
default jammy
```

**user-data**

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  identity:
    hostname: jammy-minimal
    password: $6$gnqbMUzHhQzpDEw.$.cCNVVDsDfj5Feebh.5O4VbOmib7tyjmeI2ZsFP7VK2kWwgJFbfjvXo3chpeAqCgXWVIW9oNQ/Ag85PR0IsKD/
    username: ubuntu
  version: 1
```

in the apache server logs I can see the client taking the iso, meta-data and user-data files

**/var/log/apache2/access.log**

```
192.168.42.152 - - [30/Jul/2022:09:28:21 +0000] "GET /jammy-live-server-amd64.iso HTTP/1.1" 200 1466714112 "-" "Wget"
192.168.42.152 - - [30/Jul/2022:09:28:30 +0000] "GET /jammy/meta-data HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Cloud-Init/22.1-14-g2e17a0d6-0ubuntu1~22.04.5"
192.168.42.152 - - [30/Jul/2022:09:28:30 +0000] "GET /jammy/user-data HTTP/1.1" 200 674 "-" "Cloud-Init/22.1-14-g2e17a0d6-0ubuntu1~22.04.5"
```

**On client /var/lib/cloud/data/result.json**

```
{
 "v1": {
  "datasource": "DataSourceNoCloudNet [seed=cmdline,/var/lib/cloud/seed/nocloud,http://192.168.42.151/jammy/][dsmode=net]",
  "errors": []
 }
}
```

**Screenshot**

[stuck_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MlLZ.png)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you need to specify the port you are connecting on for `s=http://192.168.42.151/jammy/` https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/datasources/nocloud.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply

I use the standard http port. but I tried to be sure.

It's the same result.

I can see downloads of user-data and meta-data files in web server logs (/var/log/apache2/access.log)

Extract of **pxelinux.cfg/default**

        append root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 ip=dhcp cloud-config-url=/dev/null url=http://192.168.42.151/jammy-live-server-amd64.iso ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.42.151:80/jammy/

Answer (score 1):

It's amazing!!!

Thank you **dummyuser** for your help. With this line the automatic installation starts.

```
append root=/dev/ram0 ramdisk_size=1500000 autoinstall ip=dhcp cloud-config-url=http://192.168.42.151/jammy/user-data url=http://192.168.42.151/jammy-live-server-amd64.iso ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.42.151/
```

The `autoinstall` option was used.
The `cloud-config-url` kernel argument setting `/dev/null` was replaced with the address and path to the `/user/data` file.

---

Pay attention to how `/dev/null` was being handled as described at [Ubuntu automated installation](https://www.molnar-peter.hu/en/ubuntu-jammy-netinstall-pxe.html#:%7E:text=Ubuntu%20automated%20installation):

> cloud-config-url=/dev/null Workaround to download install media only
> once

See [Running a truly automatic autoinstall](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall#:%7E:Running%20a%20truly%20automatic%20autoinstall):

> Even if a fully noninteractive autoinstall config is found, the server
> installer will ask for confirmation before writing to the disks unless
> autoinstall is present on the kernel command line. This is to make it
> harder to accidentally create a USB stick that will reformat a machine
> it is plugged into at boot. Many autoinstalls will be done via
> netboot, where the kernel command line is controlled by the netboot
> config – just remember to put autoinstall in there!

---

I couldn't find after 2 weeks of troubleshooting.
I can say that the problem solved.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue some days ago when upgrading my PXE env from 20.04.3 to 20.04.4. 20.04.04 is the Version you use, too. (same size of iso)
See

- [pxe autoinstall fails with ubuntu 20.04.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420641/pxe-autoinstall-fails-with-ubuntu-20-04-04)
  and the references there.

I think your user-data is a bit short, but as it is never loaded this is not the root error.

- Does any Service fail during Boot (seen in console Boot log)?
- please check the `cloud-config-url` in the append line this is new pointing now directly to the user-data file in my case. (with 20.04.3 it was `/dev/null`)
- guess you do not have any errors in the tftplog (if you have a log) ?