# cloud-config not being picked up by auto install

Tags: cloud-init

I'm trying to build my first vm image using Packer.io, vmware fusion and Ubuntu 22.04 autoinstall.
Following this example
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHaG_ra5QFw

Packer creates the vmx, start the vm and passes the boot commands to grub successfully.  The ubuntu installer runs and eventually gets to the Welcome screen waiting for language selection.
Packer fails to ssh into the vm
`SSH handshake err: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate...`
then eventually times out, kills and deletes the vm, so I have little to investigate.

watch the logs of the vm console, and Packer... It looks to me like the user-data is never retrieved.  I have verified that packer successfully started the http server, and user-data is available.   For unknown reason, it doesn't appear the ubuntu installer is trying or at least successful retrieving user-data... which would explain the ssh failure as the user was never created...

Although the logs scream by on the vnc console, I've paused and looked through them and see no indication that ubuntu is retrieving user-data...

Answer (score 0):

check your web Server log, you can see clearly the download of the iso image and if so the download of the user-data file. There seems to be similar issues user-data file not picked up by Cloudconfig in
[Install with PXE of ubuntu 22.04 blocked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421117/install-with-pxe-of-ubuntu-22-04-blocked)
and
[pxe autoinstall fails with ubuntu 20.04.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420641/pxe-autoinstall-fails-with-ubuntu-20-04-04)
you may test to adopt the `cloud-config-url` pointing directly to your user-data
pls share the log of your web server if if fails.

Comment: Packer is providing the http server.  I can't find logs for it. but I can point my browser and get the files, so I know it is sufficiently serving user-data