# ubuntu-server 20.04 automatically generated user-data does not work in autoinstall

Tags: server, cloud-init

According to the ubuntu manual, the automatically generated autoinstall-user-data will just work. However, when I try to use it to seed the server, it report shcema error:

[image]

Is this file actually non-usable

Comment: My experience using the `/var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data` file is that it will give errors.  Each Ubuntu release contains a newer version of the installer, so the errors vary based on the release.  I would use sample `user-data` files and merge in whatever sections you need customized.  My stock `user-data` file is in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1235724/376778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated autoinstall-user-data had an extra level of 'kernel' in it.
This has been [resolved](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/pull/1060) on the Subiquity main branch.  For existing autoinstall files, if you have something like the following:

```
kernel:
  kernel:
    package: linux-generic
```

please change it to look like:

```
kernel:
  package: linux-generic.
```