# "No filesystem could mount root, tried:" when trying to install Ubuntu from Ubuntu PXE Server

Tags: boot, server, pxe

I repost my topic again with Ubuntu only. I'm sorry for the confusion.
I am a newbie to set up the PXE Server. Forgive me if anything is weird in my setup. I have tried to install Ubuntu from ISO file "ubuntu-20.04.6-live-server-amd64.iso" under UEFI boot from Ubuntu PXE Server, i got the issue below

```
[   49.073558] PM:   Magic number: 8:683:869
[   49.121628] acpi device:e2: hash matches
[   49.168605] processor cpu29: hash matches
[   49.216599] rtc_cmos 00:00: setting system clock to 2024-01-26T04:53:11 UTC (1706244791)
[   49.319976] md: Waiting for all devices to be available before autodetect
[   49.401235] md: If you don't use raid, use raid=noautodetect
[   49.469055] md: Autodetecting RAID arrays.
[   49.518028] md: autorun ...
[   49.551411] md: ... autorun DONE.
[   49.591054] VFS: Cannot open root device "ram0" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
[   49.678503] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
[   49.778446] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[   49.877349] CPU: 12 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.4.0-144-generic #161-Ubuntu
[   49.970011] Hardware name: Dell WHITLEY, BIOS 1.0 10/13/2015
[   50.054355] Call Trace:
[   50.083586]  dump_stack+0x6d/0x8b
[   50.123205]  panic+0x101/0x2e3
[   50.159709]  mount_block_root+0x23f/0x2e8
[   50.207651]  mount_root+0x38/0x3a
[   50.247274]  prepare_namespace+0x13f/0x194
[   50.296260]  kernel_init_freeable+0x265/0x289
[   50.348365]  ? rest_init+0xb0/0xb0
[   50.389028]  kernel_init+0xe/0x110
[   50.429693]  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40
[   50.472453] Kernel Offset: 0x2d600000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[   50.601506] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---
```

Below is my setup on Ubuntu PXE Server
Config file:

```
#setup console
serial 0 9600

#perform a local boot by default
default mfg
#boot automatically after 30 seconds in tenths of a second
time out 300

#Ramdisk support

label mfg

   KERNEL /ubuntu/ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz
   APPEND  root=/dev/ram0 rw load_ramdisk=1 initrd=/ubuntu/ubuntu/casper/initrd ramdisk_size=3500000 console=ttyS0,9600n8 console=tty0,9600n8
```

Directory of image folder:

```
root@Ubuntu-Server1:/tftpboot/ubuntu/ubuntu/casper# dir
extras                   hwe-initrd          installer.squashfs.gpg
filesystem.manifest      hwe-vmlinuz         squashfs.manifest
filesystem.squashfs      initrd              vmlinuz
filesystem.squashfs.gpg  installer.squashfs
root@Ubuntu-Server1:/tftpboot/ubuntu/ubuntu/casper#
```

My Ubuntu PXE Server is

```
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-170-generic
```

Is there anything wrong with my Ubuntu PXE Server that can be changed to fix the issue? Many Thanks if you could help.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Where do you have the `KERNEL` and `APPEND` lines from? The error appears to be that there is no ramdisk, which probably means that the vmlinuz image doesn't have the necessary driver. As far as I can tell, the Live ISO starts without this; you'd need only the `initrd=` argument.

Comment: It stands out that your do not have a `url=*.iso` argument.  Take a look at more examples of the boot commands.  This is how I set it up https://askubuntu.com/a/1235724/376778

Comment: I used the same setup for BIOS (legacy) mode and it worked. Don't know why it does not work on UEFI